# Moving tapes out of a Bacula pool after media error

Tags: bacula

We recently ran into a situation where we had 3 volumes in an `Error` state that were clogging up our 'Default' pool.

We have several media pools for different purposes and thus have the `Maximum Volumes` directive in place so we become aware of problems (e.g. *this* problem, sudden increase of data volume, etc.).

My `Default` pool is:

```
Pool { 
  Name = Default
  Pool Type = Backup
  Recycle = yes
  Recycle Oldest Volume = yes
  RecyclePool = Scratch
  AutoPrune = yes                     # Prune expired volumes
  Volume Retention = 60 days
  Maximum Volumes = 35
  Cleaning Prefix = "CLN"
}
```

Job retention parameters were set such that we couldn't purge a tape or add another one into the pool:

```
17-Mar 23:05 server8-dir JobId 10652: Start Backup JobId 10652, Job=server1.2012-03-17_23.05.00_57
17-Mar 23:05 server8-dir JobId 10652: Warning: Unable add Scratch Volume, Pool "Default" full MaxVols=35
17-Mar 23:05 server8-dir JobId 10652: Pruning oldest volume "000026L2"
17-Mar 23:05 server8-dir JobId 10652: Using Device "TS3200-1a"
17-Mar 23:05 server8-dir JobId 10652: Warning: Unable add Scratch Volume, Pool "Default" full MaxVols=35
17-Mar 23:05 server8-dir JobId 10652: Pruning oldest volume "000026L2"
17-Mar 23:05 server8-sd JobId 10652: Job server1.2012-03-17_23.05.00_57 is waiting. Cannot find any appendable volumes.
Please use the "label" command to create a new Volume for:
    Storage:      "TS3200-1a" (/dev/nst0)
    Pool:         Default
    Media type:   LTO3
```

Is there a way to tell Bacula to move any `Error`ed volumes out of a pool automatically so they don't take up space? One of them had been there for a while (since `2011-08-20 00:10:34`) so I don't think it would have ever been moved out.

The emphasis here is for this to happen *automatically* - I think it makes sense for a volume to get moved out of the pool when `RecyclePool` is set.

(background: we maintain Bacula for quite a few different customers and we try to have things happen as automatically as possible. While this isn't a *massive* problem, perhaps this just doesn't exist yet and ought to be submitted as a feature request.)

Answer (score 5):

The great thing about Bacula is there's a whole bunch of ways to resolve any problems you may encounter.
Here are a few options for this situation:

**Option 1:**
Delete the error'd volumes outright (`delete volume` at the bacula console, then select the ones you want to get rid of).
This one is my choice if you're sure the volume is bad/defective -- No sense keeping it around anywhere if you can't use it.  Volume deletion is a catalog operation that doesn't affect the tape, so should you need to ever recover data from it you can always use [bscan](http://www.bacula.org/manuals/en/utility/utility/Volume_Utility_Tools.html#SECTION00270000000000000000) to create catalog entries and recover whatever can be read.

**Option 2:**
Get rid of the `Maximum Volumes` directive in your pool.
This guarantees you'll never have to deal with this problem again but also means you can create an infinite number of volumes if you screw up a label command. (I generally don't set `Maximum Volumes` on my pools -- It makes adding new tapes when your backup size grows more annoying than it needs to be).

**Option 3:**
Re-Label the volume (`relabel` at the bacula console, then select the volume(s) you want to move).
Note that the volume must be marked as `Purged` or `Recycled` before you can relabel it -- All of these are catalog operations (they don't need/affect the actual tape/volume) so you can run `purge volume` on the failed volumes and then `relabel` them into another pool if you so desire.
(`purge volume` can override/ignore job retention parameters -- or more accurately it ***WILL*** purge the volume, regardless of any retention parameters.  It's a tactical nuke and should be handled with care.)

**Option 4:**
I've been assuming we're talking about real tapes -- if these are virtual tape files and the "error" state is from some previous transient incident you can use `update volume` to clear the error (set it to any appropriate non-error status).  You should obviously only do this if you are certain the volume in question is *good*

Comment: Good options! This alone would be a handy synopsis for "what to do when a Bacula volume gets into the Error state".

Comment: @MikeyB it's missing Option 0 (panic and cry in a corner praying to the gods that the data you need to recover is still on the tape somewhere)